# Error while using games_services plugin: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, 4: 4: , null)

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I wanted to use google play services in my flutter application for which i used [games_services](https://pub.dev/packages/games_services) plugin. I followed all the steps in [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-integrate-gamekit-and-google-play-services-flutter-4d3f4a4a2f77) medium post. But it still gave me this error.

```
E/flutter (27643): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, 4: 4: , null)
E/flutter (27643): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569)
E/flutter (27643): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321)
E/flutter (27643): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27643): #2      GamesServices.signIn (package:games_services/games_services.dart:52)
E/flutter (27643): #3      _WelcomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:quizbee/pages/home/welcome.dart:182)
E/flutter (27643): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706)
E/flutter (27643): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789)
E/flutter (27643): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182)
E/flutter (27643): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486)
E/flutter (27643): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282)
E/flutter (27643): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199)
E/flutter (27643): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467)
E/flutter (27643): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76)
E/flutter (27643): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117)
E/flutter (27643): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379)
E/flutter (27643): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115)
E/flutter (27643): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101)
E/flutter (27643): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218)
E/flutter (27643): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198)
E/flutter (27643): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156)
E/flutter (27643): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102)
E/flutter (27643): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86)
E/flutter (27643): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138)
E/flutter (27643): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031)
E/flutter (27643): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933)
E/flutter (27643): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273)
E/flutter (27643): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182)
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are there any success on this issue?

Comment: no. i haven't continued over this. are you facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to Google sign-in

From [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-sign_in_required)
[image: A screenshot from google docs showing that sign in required]

I think silent sign-in was failing and you have to explicitly sign in. However, in this plugin starting from version 4.0.0, we are using Google play games services which do not require this silent nor explicit sign-in and everything is handled internally.